# How to find second,third,etc maximum peak of list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, peak-detection

I need to find all values of peaks.
I have `Table` with 10000 elements in it and I plot a graphic using `ListPlot`.
[image]

Then I tried to find peaks:

```
tbl1 = Table[tbl[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[tbl]}];
gA = Max[tbl1]
gAm = Part[tbl, Position[tbl1 , gA ][[1, 1]], 1]
```

Here `tbl` my Table with Data
And get:

```
0.15
8.751
```

So I find the last peak starting. How I can find other?
[image]
I upload a .txt file with data to my google drive
[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bb1tnaonF2gmctmejeeXuvCuNftf2DZP) .

I also tried to use FindPeaks but it's wrong:

```
peakpositions = FindPeaks[tbl[[All, 2]]]
```

> {{116, 0.}, {1441, 0.}}

```
peakwavelengths = tbl[[#1, 1]] & @@@ peakpositions
```

> {0.115, 1.44}

```
ListPlot[tbl, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> {peakwavelengths, None}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `FindPeaks`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I added the result above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jumps = tbl[[1 + Flatten@Position[Sign@Differences[tbl[[All, 2]]], 1]]]
```

> {{0.232, 0.05}, {2.411, 0.05}, {5.449, 0.1}, {8.751, 0.15}}

```
ListStepPlot[tbl,  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[jumps]}, 
 GridLines -> Transpose[jumps]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Pick[tbl,Join[{0},Sign@Differences[Last/@tbl]],1]
```

> {{0.232, 0.05}, {2.411, 0.05}, {5.449, 0.1}, {8.751, 0.15}}